# Need help converting to Do-While loop

Tags: c#, do-while

```
using System;
using System.Linq;


namespace PleaseHelpMe
{
    public class SumAndAverage
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
            Console.WriteLine("The sum is "+ data.Sum());
            Console.WriteLine("The average is " + data.Average());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I need to change this to a Do-While loop with an expected output  sum of 5050 and an average of 50.

Comment: I'm afraid you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: It's clear you have made some effort in asking your question, but showing your attempt at converting this code to a do/while loop would have made the question better. Fortunately for you, I'm in a good mood so I've provided an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A `do`/`while` loop is a bit of a strange choice here, I think. A better choice would be a `for` loop.

Anyway, you'll need to track the `count` and the current iteration `i`:

```
int i = 1;
int count = 100;
```

You will also need to store the `sum`. For big values (sum > 2147483647) you should use `long`:

```
int sum = 0;
```

Now you'll need to increment `i` until it matches `count`:

```
do
{
    sum += i; // add current value of i to sum.
}
while (i++ < count);
```

Note that I've used `i++` here because it returns the value of `i` *before* it is incremented, in contrast to `++i` which returns the value of `i` *after* it is incremented. If `++i` were used, you would have to compare it with `<=`.

Finally calculate the average and output the sum:

```
double average = sum / (double)count;
Console.WriteLine("The sum is " + sum);
Console.WriteLine("The average is " + average);
Console.ReadKey();
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/CTV63651)

I think that a `for` loop is better suited to this (although I understand if it's for an assignment you probably have to jump through the hoops of using `do`/`while`):

```
int sum = 0;
int count = 100;

for (int i = 1; i <= count; ++i)
{
    sum += i;
}
double average = sum / (double)count;
Console.WriteLine("The sum is " + sum);
Console.WriteLine("The average is " + average);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I wonder if this _homework_ also expects the code to store the 1-100 range in an array, like the original code.

Comment: @Andrew The original has no array, nor is it storing the original values. [`Enumerable.Range`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,1265) just yields values [using a `for` loop](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,1271).

Comment: Oh, you are right. It just _looks like_ the values were stored there. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum = 0;   
decimal avg = 0;  
do   
{   
    sum += n;  
    avg = sum/n;  
    n++;  
}  while (n <= 100);
```

This should works.

Comment: Why calculate the average on every single cycle instead of just at the end? `n` is not declared or initialized.

Comment: @Andrew, thanks to remind me define n. In question he is calculating avg for each time as well.

Comment: He's calculating it just once at the end, just as with the sum.